# wire:model="image" anulls my js-scripts and $_GET array | Laravel Livewire WithFileUploads

Tags: laravel, file-upload, upload, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component

```
class UploadImageForm extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $image;

    public function save()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate([
            'image' => 'image|max:1024',
        ]);
        
        $path = $validatedData['image']->store('storage', 'public');        

        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        User::where('id', $userId)
            ->update([
                'image' => $path,
            ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.upload-image-form');
    }
}
```

And html

```
<div class="mt-2">
    <form class="ava-form" wire:submit.prevent="save" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;width: 50%;height: 250px;">
        <div class="file-container">
            <div class="file-overlay"></div>
            <div class="file-wrapper"><input
                    wire:model="image"
                    class="file-input"
                    id="js-file-input"
                    type="file" />
                <div class="file-content">
                    <div class="file-infos">
                        <p class="file-icon">
                            <span class="icon-shadow"></span><span>Browse</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="file-name" id="js-file-name">No file selected</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @error('image') <span class="error mt-2">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        <button type="submit" class="mt-3 btn btn-dark rounded-pill">Wgrywać</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I upload the file the script trying to update the file name instead of "No file selected". But it can't do this because of wire:model="image". It updating scripts and even $_GET and returning the page to the start state.
Help please, tell how to turn off this script update? Because I want to get custom upload form but I can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to prevent Livewire from updating the component with each upload:

1. Use `wire:model.defer` instead of `wire:model`. This way, Livewire won't update the component.
2. Use `wire:ignore` for `.file-wrapper`, which will make Livewire ignore this element (and its children).

The reason you cannot use custom JS is because Livewire updates the element with each request. With these two options, you can prevent this behavior.